# Extracting text from NAs using R and tidyr()

Tags: regex, r, tidyr, stringr

I have four columns of data within a data frame. These columns specify whether a record (row) sits within 4 different parts of London according to a north/south/east/west split (NO record is present in more than ONE column), thus (where the first row is the column header):

```
North    South     East    West
NA       South     NA      NA
NA       NA        East    NA
North    NA        NA      NA
```

I want to use these as a factor in a chart, so using tidyr I concatenated them

```
LondonNew <- unite(London,"adminarea",North:West,sep="",remove=FALSE)
```

, so that I now have an additional column called adminarea:

```
adminarea
NASouthNANA
NANAEastNA
NorthNANANA
```

I couldn't find an argument within tidyr() to ignore NAs and wonder whether this is possible? Worst case, can someone help me with a simple additional regex/str_extract that will help me extract just the four words North, South, East or West into a separate column?

The goal is to have:

```
adminarea
South
East
North
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Use LondonNew$adminarea <- gsub('NA', '', LondonNew$adminarea)

Comment: It will work in this case, but not always if other portions of the text also have NA that are valid.

Comment: This is a classic case for matrix indexing - `dat[cbind(seq_len(nrow(dat)),max.col(!is.na(dat)))]` will do all the `unite` plus `NA` removal in one go.

Comment: Another option, if it fits your use case, is to replace the NA with the empty string first.  Example: `London[is.na(London)] <- ''` then run `LondonNew <- unite(London,"adminarea",North:West,sep="",remove=FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
LondonNew$adminarea <- gsub('NA', '', LondonNew$adminarea)
```

This will work because of the special nature of your combined string. It won't if NA is a valid character sequence in that column.